# Offline Install of Package using Visual Studio is very slow

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We program in a high security area that has no connection to the internet. Hence, to install a package in a Visual Studio project we put it on a shared drive (if not already there) and Visual Studio points ONLY to that shared drive for packages. This does work but every install contains at least a 1-minute stall/hang right after it displays 'Installing abc.def 0.0'. This is despite the fact that nuget is NOT listed as a source - only the shared drive is a package source. It would appear that under the covers package install is still trying to access the internet and times out after 1 minute allowing the install to proceed. Is there any way to remove this delay?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the delay is caused by your nuget package itself or VS.

Please make sure if every nuget package from the shared drive has the same behavior.

Try the following suggestions:

**1)** disable any third party installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed** in case some extensions cause that.

**2)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

**3)** type  `devenv /safemode` under **Developer Command Prompt for VS** to start a new initial VS to test your issue.

**4)** close VS, delete `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming`. Then, restart VS to readd the new shared drive path under nuget package source. After that, test your nuget packages again.

**5)** turn off any safety protection programs or third party os programs if you have.

**6)** if your VS is not latest, you could update it to the latest VS2019 version.

Comment: Tried your suggestions. Could not complete 3) as that results in a curious message saying the project needed to be migrated??  I also did not upgrade from 16.6.2. as I have some deadlines to meet first.  Bottomline - no change to the issue. But I may have a clue: if an install package errors out because the system cannot find all the components, then the next package install of something for which we have all the components has this hang.

Comment: If the prompt reminders some tools, you have to install them on the vs_installer. Besides, what is your project type? safemode is the initial environment of vs and it should not change your project. So what is your project type and its targetframework. If you follow the suggestion,  did the situation disappear？

Comment: The project is a console app, .Net Core 3.1, the single empty project in the solution.

Comment: If you try to change to use a local nuget source under your PC disk itself, did the situation happen? Also, uninstall VS,could it help?